# Accessing variables between swift classes

Tags: variables, swift

When using objective c we can create a variable in one class, for example:

```
//  ArticleCell.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ArticleTitleLabel;

@interface ArticleCell : UITableViewCell
{

    ArticleTitleLabel *_titleLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ArticleTitleLabel *titleLabel;

@end
```

Then in our other class we can use an import statement and use that variable. For example:

[image: picture of titleLabel used in other file]

However, when I'm using swift and declare a variable:

```
class ArticleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    var titleLabel:UILabel!
```

and then try and use that variable within another class within the same project I get the following error:

[image: image showing error when using variable in another class]

What are we supposed to do here? Construct a strut and have a global static variable or what is the correct method?

Comment: Your error is informing you that it thinks `cell` is a `UITableViewCell`, not an `ArticleTableViewCell`. Take a look at your `cell` declaration.

Comment: I guess when you're dequeueing the cell you're casting it to a `UITableViewCell` instead of `ArticleCell`.

Comment: Correct it was all to do with the casting of the ArticleTableViewCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dequeue the cell you'll need to cast it to `ArticleCell`, where the `titleLabel` is defined.  One way to do this is to extend `UITableViewCell` with a `configureCell()` method and let dynamic dispatch call the proper method:

```
  public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
  }
```

Another less general approach is like:

```
  public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    if let articleCell = cell as? ArticleCell {
       articleCell.titleLabel.text = // ...
    }
    else { // other or unexpected cell type }
  }
```